# Fill column with value from previous year from the same month

Tags: python, pandas

How can I use the value from the same month in the previous year to fill values in the following table for 2020:

```
Category   Month   Year   Value
  A          1     2019    15
  B          2     2019    20
  A          2     2019    90
  A          3     2019    50
  B          4     2019    40
  A          5     2019    20
  A          6     2019    15
  A          7     2019    17
  A          8     2019    18
  A          9     2019    12
  A          10    2019    11
  A          11    2019    19
  A          12    2019    15
  A          1     2020    18
  A          2     2020    53
  A          3     2020    80
```

The final desired result is the following:

```
Category   Month   Year   Value
  A          1     2019    15
  B          2     2019    20
  A          2     2019    90
  A          3     2019    50
  B          4     2019    40
  A          4     2019    40
  A          5     2019    20
  A          6     2019    15
  A          7     2019    17
  A          8     2019    18
  A          9     2019    12
  A          10    2019    11
  A          11    2019    19
  A          12    2019    15
  A          1     2020    18
  A          2     2020    53
  A          3     2020    80
  B          4     2020    40
  A          4     2020    40
  A          5     2020    20
  A          6     2020    15
  A          7     2020    17
  A          8     2020    18
  A          9     2020    12
  A          10    2020    11
  A          11    2020    19
  A          12    2020    15
```

I tried using pandas groupby but not sure if that is the right approach.

Comment: Please provide your data in a more convenient format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the `pivot` then `ffill` with `stack`:

```
s=df.pivot_table(index=['Category','Year'],columns='Month',values='Value').groupby(level=0).ffill().stack().reset_index()
   Category  Year  level_2     0
0         A  2019        1  15.0
1         A  2019        2  90.0
2         A  2019        3  50.0
3         A  2019        5  20.0
4         A  2019        6  15.0
5         A  2019        7  17.0
6         A  2019        8  18.0
7         A  2019        9  12.0
8         A  2019       10  11.0
9         A  2019       11  19.0
10        A  2019       12  15.0
11        A  2020        1  18.0
12        A  2020        2  53.0
13        A  2020        3  80.0
14        A  2020        5  20.0
15        A  2020        6  15.0
16        A  2020        7  17.0
17        A  2020        8  18.0
18        A  2020        9  12.0
19        A  2020       10  11.0
20        A  2020       11  19.0
21        A  2020       12  15.0
22        B  2019        2  20.0
23        B  2019        4  40.0
```

Comment: Any recommendation on how I could assign the value of 0 if a month is missing from 2019 for a specific category?  As an example, there is no row for Category B in Month 1 for 2019.  I would want to then use 0 for Month 1 in both 2019 and 2020.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with a combination of `loc`, `concat`, and `drop_duplicates`.

The idea here is to concatenate the dataframe with a copy of the 2019 data where year is changed to 2020, and then only keeping the first value for Category, Month, Year.

```
df2 = df.loc[df['Year'] == 2019, :]
df2['Year'] = 2020
pd.concat([df, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Category', 'Month', 'Year'], keep='first')
```

Output

```
   Category  Month  Year  Value
0         A      1  2019     15
1         B      2  2019     20
2         A      2  2019     90
3         A      3  2019     50
4         B      4  2019     40
5         A      5  2019     20
6         A      6  2019     15
7         A      7  2019     17
8         A      8  2019     18
9         A      9  2019     12
10        A     10  2019     11
11        A     11  2019     19
12        A     12  2019     15
13        A      1  2020     18
14        A      2  2020     53
15        A      3  2020     80
1         B      2  2020     20
4         B      4  2020     40
5         A      5  2020     20
6         A      6  2020     15
7         A      7  2020     17
8         A      8  2020     18
9         A      9  2020     12
10        A     10  2020     11
11        A     11  2020     19
12        A     12  2020     15
```